# Android - ArrayList<Integer> not displaying properly in custom listVIew

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have a custom listView with three textViews. The data comes from a class with three ArrayLists, two of which are strings and the last one is an Integer. I have no problems populating and adding items to the list as I saw that when I displayed the ArrayList values on logCat via `log.d`, all three ArrayLists had their respectful items.

It seems to me that there is something wrong with the way I display data.

Here are the files:
list_row_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/variant"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="variant" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="quantity" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/unit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="221dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/quantity"
    android:text="unit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the part in my activity_order_form.xml that has the listView element.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewVariantB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
        android:text="Variant"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewUnit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="123dp"
        android:text="Unit"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewProductOrder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewVariantB" >

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the class where the ArrayList are stored.

```
public class CurrentOrderClass {

  private String productName;

  //ArrayLists
  private ArrayList<String> variantArray = new ArrayList<String>();
  private ArrayList<String> unitArray = new ArrayList<String>();
  private ArrayList<Integer> quantityArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();


  //TODO ArrayList functions
  public ArrayList<String> getUnitArray() {
    return unitArray;
  }

  public void setUnitArray(ArrayList<String> unitArray) {
    this.unitArray = unitArray;
  }

  public void addToUnitArray(String unit){
    this.unitArray.add(unit);
  }



  public ArrayList<Integer> getQuantityArray() {
    return quantityArray;
  }

  public void setQuantityArray(ArrayList<Integer> quantityArray) {
    this.quantityArray = quantityArray;
  }

  public void addToQuantityArray(int quantity){
    this.quantityArray.add(quantity);
  }



  public ArrayList<String> getVariantArray() {
    return variantArray;
  }

  public void setVariantArray(ArrayList<String> variantArray) {
    this.variantArray = variantArray;
  }

  public void addToVariantArray(String variantArray){
    this.variantArray.add(variantArray);
  }
}
```

Here is the CustomListAdapter.java file

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  private ArrayList<CurrentOrderClass> listData;

  private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

  public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CurrentOrderClass> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.variantView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.variant);
        holder.unitView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.unit);
        holder.quantityView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.variantView.setText(listData.get(position).getVariantArray().get(position).toString());
    holder.unitView.setText(listData.get(position).getUnitArray().get(position).toString());
    holder.quantityView.setText(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).getQuantityRow()));

    return convertView;
}

  static class ViewHolder {
    TextView variantView;
    TextView unitView;
    TextView quantityView;
  }

public void setListData(ArrayList<CurrentOrderClass> data){
    listData = data;
}

}
```

This is part of my OrderForm.java activity, this shows the onCreate and the method that populates the listView.

```
public class OrderForm extends Activity {

  public TextView tv;
  private int variantPosition; 
  CustomListAdapter customListAdapter;
  CurrentOrderClass currentOrder = new CurrentOrderClass();

  @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_form);
          tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewProduct);

          //set variants here
          popolateItem();

          //set current order listview here
          ArrayList image_details = getListData();
          final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewProductOrder);

          customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, image_details);
          lv1.setAdapter(customListAdapter);

  }

  private ArrayList getListData() {

      ArrayList results = new ArrayList();

      if(currentOrder.getQuantityArray().size() > 10){
        loopUntil = currentOrder.getQuantityArray().size();

        for(int i = 0; i < loopUntil; i++){
            currentOrder.getQuantityArray();
            currentOrder.getUnitArray();
            currentOrder.getVariantArray();
            results.add(currentOrder);
        }

    }
    else{
        loopUntil = 10;

        for(int i = 0; i < loopUntil; i++){
            currentOrder.getQuantityArray().add(i);
            currentOrder.getUnitArray().add("Sample text here." + i);
            currentOrder.getVariantArray().add("Another sample text here" + i);
            results.add(currentOrder);
        }
    }
    return results;     
  }
}
```

When I execute a `Log.d` statement to display the contents of my ArrayLists, it shows that my quantityArray has elements [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9].

I know I can just convert quantityArray to an ArrayList from an ArayList, but I don't want to do that.

I think there's something wrong with my CustomListAdapter.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

I changed

`holder.quantityView.setText(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).getQuantityRow()));`

to

`holder.quantityView.setText(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).getQuantityArray().get(position)));`

Answer (score 0):

There is no where that you actually set the view, as in, it doesn't do anything, if convertView is null, you can't call any methods of it, convertView, if its is not null, will be `ViewHolder` in your context, what you need to do is have an object which is extending some type of view, instantiate it, give it methods to set the values, things like that.

For example here is what I use in an adapter that displays simple messages:

```
public class MessageView extends RelativeLayout {

    private TextView mBody;

    private String mBodyString = "";

    private boolean mDrawn = false;

    private boolean mLocal = false;

    public MessageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.drawView();
    }

    public MessageView(Context context, String body) {
        super(context);
        mBodyString = body;
        this.drawView();
    }

    public MessageView(Context context, String body, boolean local) {
        super(context);
        mBodyString = body;
        mLocal = local;
        this.drawView();
    }

    private void drawView() {
        if (mDrawn)
            return;
        mDrawn = true;

        this.removeAllViews();
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

        if(mLocal){
            this.addView(li.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_device, this, false),
                    params);
        }else{
            this.addView(li.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_remote, this, false),
                    params);
        }

        mBody = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tMessage);
        mBody.setText(mBodyString);
    }

    public void setLocal(){
        this.setLocal(true);
    }

    public void setLocal(boolean local){
        mLocal = local;
        mDrawn = false;
        this.drawView();
    }

    public void setMessage(String body){
        mBodyString = body;
        mBody.setText(mBodyString);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's weird because I can see and set the two ArrayList<String> in the listView.

Comment: I think I am reading something wrong, however in the if/else the else statement will throw a NullPointerException if it is ever run.

Comment: There's a part in my code that takes in user input and updates the listView, I did not put my whole code in.